# discord.js | cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I was trying to write in an embed in my discord music bot command to tell the author of the command when and what the bot was playing.

Now, I've tried passing in different arguments (such as messageembed itself) and this isn't working.

I've only been coding for maybe 6 months now, so I'm not the best

here is my code (the bit that I'm having trouble with at least)

```
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
        const stream = ytdl(song.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
        song_queue.connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 0.5})
        .on('finish', () => {
            song_queue.songs.shift();
            video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
        });
        const replyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF2D00')
        .setTitle(' Now Playing ')
        .setDescription(`${song.title} [${message.author}]`)

        await song_queue.text_channel.send(replyEmbed)
}
```

Comment: That means `Discord` is undefined. Where is it coming from?

Comment: The code looks fine, do you have something like `const Discord = require("discord.js");` at the top of the file the code is in?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code that you have is just a snippet taken from your file, but from the error I can assume that `Discord` has not been defined.

Please make sure to include this at the top of your file:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems you may have forgotten to require discord.js. Do this like so:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

If you have got something that looks like this at the top of the file, but you have a different constant name, i.e. not `Discord`, replace `Discord` in `Discord.MessageEmbed()` with whatever your constant is called.